# How do I add 'active' class dynamically on vue js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My view is like this :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
    @foreach($countries as $country)
        <li role="presentation" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab" @click="$refs.player.getPlayer({{ $country->id }})">{{ ucfirst($country->name) }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I want add `class="active"` in li tag. So, when the tab clicked, the li tag will active

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for) to loop through a variable in vue.js and use index to check for the first element. Use [v-bind:class](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to apply a class dynamically. The correct solution for doing this should be:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
    <li v-for="(country, index) as {$countries}" role="presentation" :class="{index == 0 : 'active'}"><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab" @click="$refs.player.getPlayer(country.id )">{{ ucfirst(country.name) }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There exist error : `Undefined variable: country (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\resources\views\front.blade.php)`. `$countries` taken from the controller. I use laravel framework. But I collaborate with vue.js

Comment: @mosestoh You have to make `countries` available in vue instance so that you can use it in DOM. Than you can remove `{}` and it can be just `v-for="(countries, index) as country"`

Comment: It's the same. Seems it does not work in view. My code above is view. It does not component. `v-for` only work in a component. Not in the a view

Answer (score -5):

Using JQuery:

```
$("#ID").addClass("active");
```

Using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("ID").className += " active";
```

Comment: If use jquery or javascript, I can do it. But, How to implement it use vue.js 2?

Comment: what, you want a vue.js specific way of doing it? last i checked vue.js is written in javascript. that means that by using the javascript version you're doing it from scratch, all that vue.js can offer would be a wrapper for that same function that i gave you above.

Comment: "all that vue.js can offer would be a wrapper for the same function" Um...no. Vue is much more than just a simple wrapper. It's also powerful data binding and observation library. If you want to step around it and do your own thing in plain JS, that's fine too, but then there's no point in using Vue in the first place.

Comment: @DanielT. I didn't say that's all it is, I said that for the javascript done above Vue.js can't do it any differently than the above code since they do their code in javascript. Therefore, that specific above code would just be wrapped inside Vue.js if you try to do a Vue.js only solution. I understand Vue.js has other upsides, but if that above code is all you want there's no reason at all to use some Vue.js version of it.

Comment: No, Vue is a data-driven templating engine. The correct solution is to modify your data, perhaps through an `isActive` property, which in turn triggers Vue to re-render the view and add in the class. The data is always the source of truth in Vue, and the DOM nodes simply reflects that truth. What you're suggesting completely breaks that paradigm.

Comment: He doesn't have to use my solution, but nevertheless it does what he requested.

Comment: No, he requested a solution given that he's using Vue. You provided an incorrect solution given his chosen framework.